# Problem with cast from argv[] argument to uint16_t

Tags: c, casting

I have created a tcp socket connection between two pcs and now i want the client to be able to chose the ip and port from command line (./client ip port) but i'm having some problems with casting the argv argument of the port to the actual type of the port (uint16_t).
Here is the code of the function that makes the connection:
Sorry for the italian naming of variables; i marked with a ' - ' the lines that gives me the error

```
 int connettiAlServer(char **argv, char *indirizzoServer) {
      int socketDesc;
    -  uint16_t porta = (uint16_t)argv[2];
      indirizzoServer = ipResolver(argv);
      struct sockaddr_in mio_indirizzo;
      mio_indirizzo.sin_family = AF_INET;
   -  mio_indirizzo.sin_port = htons(porta);
      inet_aton(indirizzoServer, &mio_indirizzo.sin_addr);
      if ((socketDesc = socket(PF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) < 0)
        perror("Impossibile creare socket"), exit(-1);
      else
        printf("Socket creato\n");
      if (connect(socketDesc, (struct sockaddr *)&mio_indirizzo,
                  sizeof(mio_indirizzo)) < 0)
        perror("Impossibile connettersi"), exit(-1);
      else
        printf("Connesso a %s\n", indirizzoServer);
      return socketDesc;
    }
```

The error is the following regardint the first marked line:

```
warning: cast from pointer to integer of different size [-Wpointer-to-int-cast]
   45 |   uint16_t porta = (uint16_t)argv[2];
```

Comment: On an unrelated note: Please don't chain multiple expressions together using the comma operator. Write proper statements instead. It will make your code easier to read, understand and maintain.

Comment: I usually do it only with the combination of perror + exit
Is it that bad?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`argv` is, essentially, an array of *strings*. You can't convert a string to a number by simple casting. You need to use a function like [`strtoul`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtoul):

```
uint16_t porta = strtoul(argv[2], NULL, 10);
```

---

To be more specific, what happens when you do `(uint16_t) argv[2]` is to convert the *pointer* in `argv[2]` to an `uint16_t`. The resulting value will be the 16 low bits of the actual pointer itself.

Comment: Don't forget to check the port is between 0 and 65535 as well. Stupid users will try to open a port -65456t84564.